# Accordion in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hi I am working on an accordion I would like to know if there is a cleaner way of toggling the "plus" and "minus" signs. Bellow is the code and a link to a prototype.

jQuery

```
$(".discount-wrapper h2").on("click", function() {
    $(this).children('.plus-sign').toggle();
    $(this).parent().children(".discount-content-wrapper").toggle('slow');
    $(this).children('.minus-sign').toggle();
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="discount-wrapper">
    <h2>Accordion 3<i class="plus-sign">+</i><i class="minus-sign" style="display:none;">-</i></h2>
    <div class="discount-content-wrapper">
        <p>My content is here</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="discount-wrapper">
    <h2>Accordion 3<i class="plus-sign">+</i><i class="minus-sign" style="display:none;">-</i></h2>
    <div class="discount-content-wrapper">
        <p>My content is here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/ferrazzzZ/3c7qf3aa/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it with 1 i-element element instead and just toggle the class.
So on default you have an i-element without a class which shows the plus-sign. Now when you click on your h2 you just toggle the class minus-sign (in which case the plus sign is overwritten).

https://jsfiddle.net/2t3uyq4k/

```
$(".discount-wrapper h2").on("click", function() {
    $(this).children('i').toggleClass('minus-sign');
    $(this).parent().children(".discount-content-wrapper").toggle('slow');
});
```

changed html:

```
<div class="discount-wrapper">
     <h2>Accordion 3<i></i></h2>
     <div class="discount-content-wrapper">
         <p>My content is here</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="discount-wrapper">
     <h2>Accordion 3<i></i></h2>
     <div class="discount-content-wrapper">
         <p>My content is here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.discount-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:  100%;
    background-color:#f3f3f3;
    min-height:28px;
    height: auto;
}

.discount-wrapper i:after {
    content: '+';
}

.discount-wrapper i.minus-sign:after {
    content: '-';
}

.discount-content-wrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Here i have made some changes in css which remove the "jumping" while toggling (replaced margin with padding on h2 and p):
https://jsfiddle.net/dyzd85y4/

Answer (score 0):

A more cleaner appraoch will be

```js
$(".discount-wrapper h2").on("click", function() {
  $(this).children('.sign').text(function(i, t) {
    return t.trim() == '+' ? '-' : '+'
  });

  $(this).parent().children(".discount-content-wrapper").toggle('slow');
});
```

```css
.discount-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  min-height: 28px;
  height: auto;
}
.discount-content-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="discount-wrapper">
  <h2>Accordion 3<i class="sign">+</i></h2>
  <div class="discount-content-wrapper">
    <p>My content is here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="discount-wrapper">
  <h2>Accordion 3<i class="sign">+</i></h2>
  <div class="discount-content-wrapper">
    <p>My content is here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Another css based solution will be

```js
$(".discount-wrapper h2").on("click", function() {
  $(this).children('i').toggleClass('sign-plus sign-minus');

  $(this).parent().children(".discount-content-wrapper").toggle('slow');
});
```

```css
.discount-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  min-height: 28px;
  height: auto;
}
.discount-content-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
.discount-wrapper .sign-plus:after {
  content: '+'
}
.discount-wrapper .sign-minus:after {
  content: '-'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="discount-wrapper">
  <h2>Accordion 3<i class="sign-plus"></i></h2>
  <div class="discount-content-wrapper">
    <p>My content is here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="discount-wrapper">
  <h2>Accordion 3<i class="sign-plus"></i></h2>
  <div class="discount-content-wrapper">
    <p>My content is here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```